# how to update link on live site from test site

Tags: migration

Recently I uploaded a WordPress site, but the page url still displays the old test site url, and the place where my new url is displaying doesnt get the page.

Comment: Can you share some more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve and also what you have tried currently so we can better help you.

Comment: my live site url is www.example.com and it shows index page of my website, now when i click to menus it redirect to demo.example.com

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question? If so, please upvote it and click the green checkmark to let the community know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common issue when migrating to a different domain. Try one of the two options:

#### 1. Backend: execute a SQL query

Go into your database (phpMyAdmin) and execute the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'OLD_URL','NEW_URL');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'OLD_URL','NEW_URL');
```

- `OLD_URL` will be replaced with `http://demo.example.com`
- `NEW_URL` will be replaced with `http://www.example.com`

This will cover the `siteurl`, `home`, and all of your content on your website that is linking to the old URL.

#### 2. Frontend: use the [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin

A more user-friendly approach is to use the [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin to easily replace all tables that contain your old URL. The process is easy to use and you can preview what tables and rows will be affected before applying those changes.

#### Forewarning

Before applying any changes, I think it goes without saying to always make a backup of your database in the event something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it's an issue with the `siteurl` or `home` which are set in the `wp_options` table. I would suggest you follow the steps set out in this article to update the URL of the site.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL